# $A$ and $B$ be two orthogonal matrices with $|A|+|B|=0$. Then prove that $(A+B)$ is singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let , $A$ and $B$ be two orthogonal matrices with $|A|+|B|=0$. Then prove that $(A+B)$ is singular.

From the relation $|A|+|B|=0$ it is clear that $|AB|=-1$.

Also , $|A|=|B|=\pm 1$. But how I find out $|A+B|$ ?

Comment: $|A+B| = |A||E + A^{-1}B|$ and $A^{-1}B$ is also othrogonal

Comment: Then how I proceed ?

Comment: $Q = A^{-1}B$ is an othrogonal matrix with $\operatorname{det} Q = -1$. Since every eigenvalue of $Q$ has 1 as is absolute value and every complex value comes with its complex conjugate there should be $-1$ among them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You wrote $\det A \times \det B = -1$, hence, wlog assume $\det A = 1$ and $\det B = -1$.

$$\det (A+B) = \det(A+B)\det(A^{T}) = \det(I+BA^{T}) = \det(B)\det(A^T+B^T) \\= -\det(A+B)$$

det(A+B)=0

Comment: Hi. I don't come in chat anymore, but if you want we can have a talk either here or by e-mail. ;)